# How to interpret Record Type in Socrata New York City Real Property Legals database?

Tags: socrata, opendata

Can you look at https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/ERROR-in-record-type/dq2e-3a6q

This shows a record type that appears to be incorrect.

It shows

```
P:10,item":"Bloomfield"},{"count":9,item":"New Britain"},{"count":8,item":"West Htfd"},{"count":7,item":"Torrington"},{"count":6,item":"Meriden"},{"count":5,item":"Whfd"},{"count":4,item":"Manchester
```

If you select count(*) and group by record_type you see:

```
curl 'https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/636b-3b5g.json?$select=count(*),record_type&$group=record_type'
[ {
  "count" : "1",
  "record_type" : "P:10,item\":\"Bloomfield\"},{\"count\":9,item\":\"New Britain\"},{\"count\":8,item\":\"West Htfd\"},{\"count\":7,item\":\"Torrington\"},{\"count\":6,item\":\"Meriden\"},{\"count\":5,item\":\"Whfd\"},{\"count\":4,item\":\"Manchester"
}
, {
  "count" : "36631085",
  "record_type" : "P"
}
```

This means there are 36M record type's having the value "P" and one very odd one.

One suggestion for New York City Open Data Law:

We must modify the Open Data Law (http://www1.nyc.gov/site/doitt/initiatives/open-data-law.page) to require New York City Government agencies to not only to open up data but to actually use the open data portal for government agency public sites.

If we allow agencies to simply dump data into a portal, then we have no quality testing.  And agencies can trumpet how many datasets are open but no one is actually using the data.

This simple change "agency must use it's own data (aka, dogfood)" will encourage quality.  If you read, http://www1.nyc.gov/site/doitt/initiatives/open-data-law.page it only mentions quality once and nothing about usage of the data.  A portal is not a thing to brag about, it is an important way to join technology and government.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention. I'll have our support team reach out to the team at the city and see if we can get this addressed.

Comment: Thank you Chris.  We really appreciate your help.   And we appreciate Socrata.